# Make <div> fill remaining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's Bootstrap 3. I just want to split my `sidebar` into two sections. The bottom part should be high enough to fit the contents, while the top section should fill the remaining height of the parent. Following is the closest that I could achieve with my limited HTML/CSS abilities:

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar col-md-3" style="background-color: lightyellow">
            <div class="topClass" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
                Should fill the remaining height of the parent
            </div>
            <div class="bottomClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;">
                Should be high enough to fit its contents
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

    .sidebar .topClass {
        position: absolute;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; 
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .sidebar .bottomClass {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

I see a very similar problems listed on Google machine, but in my case I don't know the height of the other `<div>`, so I think I can't use the new `calc` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a solution that works for Chromium and Chrome but not for FF and I didn't test it on further browsers.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="table stretch-v">
        <div class="row stretch-v">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="top-class stretch">
                    Some Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="bottom-class">
                    Some other Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.sidebar{height: 100%; background:grey;}
.table {display:table;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {display:table-cell;}
.stretch-v {height:100%;}
.stretch {width:100%; height:100%;}
.top-class{overflow:auto;}
```

And this is what it looks like: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4re8kyn/84/)**

Comment: This is the best solution I have got so far. I'll accept it as answer till someone comes up with a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `postion:fixed` or `position:absolute`. Use `table` and `table-row` to get the desired result.

```
body,html{height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
.container-fluid, .sidebar{height:100%; background:grey; display:table; width:100%;}
.topClass{display:table-row; height:100%;}
.bottomClass{display:table-row;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4re8kyn/)

Comment: Try adding some content to the top <div> to create overflow. At that point, I want it to keep its layout by simply adding a scrollbar. Instead it expands and pushes the bottom <div> downwards. Adding `overflow: scroll` to the top <div> also doesn't help. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine showed me a better solution using `flex layout` that works at least for Firefox and Chrome/Chromium.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="top">
    Should fill the remaining height of the parent<br />
    and bring up a scrollbar on overflow.
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Should be high enough to fit its content.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html { height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
.sidebar { height:100%; display: flex; flex-direction:column; }
.sidebar > .top { flex-grow:1; overflow:auto; }
.sidebar > .bottom { flex:0 0 content; }
```

I also updated the fiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4re8kyn/110/)

Comment: Thank you. This is a great solution. flex-grow: 1 allow the content section to fill the whole screen, while the flex: 0 0 content will remain at the bottom no matter the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just add height 100% in topClass tag

```
<div class="topClass" style="background-color: lightcoral;height:100%">
```

CORRECTED HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar col-md-3" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
            <div class="topClass" style="background-color: lightcoral;height:100%">
                Should fill the remaining height of the parent
            </div>
            <div class="bottomClass" style="background-color: lightcyan;">
                Should be high enough to fit its contents
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
                A few lines of text <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Incorrect solution. This makes the top <div> take 100% of the window height. As I have mentioned in the post title and body, I need it to fill *remaining* height, i.e. top div height = window height - bottom div height.